# How to fix windshield washer pump in Yaris Verso

Tags: toyota, windshield

My windshield washer pump in my Toyota Yaris Verso has stopped working. The fuse seems to be fine, so either it's due to a loose connection, or the pump is broken. What is the likely cause, and how can I access the pump?

Comment: @MarkJohnson: thanks for getting back to me. Yes - the pump motor had to be replaced, as simple as that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pump is usually mounted to the bottom of the tank.

Common causes of failure:

- Disconnected or clogged hose with the engine off can you hear the motor running under the hood? If so could be a clogged or disconnected hose.
- Wax or other debris in the jets, if the jets are located on the hood they can get clogged with wax or dirt, if you hear the pump motor running and there are no disconnected or clogged hoses this may be your problem.
- Bad motor, check for voltage at the terminals connected to the motor
- If no voltage to the motor you may have a bad wiper switch

Comment: Thanks! I don't hear the pump so I guess it's either a bad motor or a bad switch. I'll have to access it first, which isn't easy without lifting the car.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a faulty windshield washer pump motor changed in my Yaris once. This one is not so easy to access. The mechanic replaced it via front right wheel area after removing front guard. He said this way is better other wise he'll have to remove front bumper, headlight then washer water tank to get to motor. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Remove front right tire, remove plastic guard, remove wiring connection and water tube from washer pump, then remove washer pump. Going through the bumper is more tedious.

Answer (score 0):

I have also a faulty front washer yaris 2013... But better check first before you buy a replacement..mine stop woking  because of rusty connectors because water leakage.. I try clean it with wd40... brushed it then test it now its working.. 
I believe pump motor is sealed so 95% its still good[image]